# Out of x channels, only one transitions from state OPEN to CONNECTED

Tags: netty

I'm fairly new to both network programming in general and Netty in particular, so pray forgive my ignorance.

I wrote a small server using Netty's NIO transport, and thus far everything went smoothly. Now I implemented a test that tries to verify that my server does indeed support multiple concurrent connections. Much to my surprise, out of x (I tried different numbers between 10 and 100) connections to my server I open with a test client, only one transitions from state OPEN via BOUND to CONNECTED. All the others never make it past OPEN.

Before I dive into implementation details I would rather like to know whether someone can think of a general explanation for this phenomenon, or has experienced the same problem. Any hints are appreciated.

Regards,
Olaf

Comment: Would you mind if you could provide us a minimal sample app that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: Trustin, I will see what I can do. Won't be easy though.

Comment: Are you using a NioServerSocketChannelFactory with dedicated boss and worker executors?

Comment: @forty-two: Yes, indeed I do. Does that hint at a possible explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that forty-two was on the right track: buried deeply somewhere inside spring xml config lurched a thread pool configuration that set both core pool size and max pool size to 1. Stupid me.